# How do I make a logo small while the content scroll up in angular like any whatsapp number profile viewing

Tags: angular

I am doing a demo project in angular and i need to make my profile picture smaller and from the center of the screen to the upper left side of the screen in angular when the content scroll-up.
This is similar to when we view a whatsapp number's profile and do scroll-up to see the rest of the content , that time profile pic and phone number goes from the center to upper left corner.

I may not clarify you the details by writing... so i record a screen and take a screenshot of what i did...

Expecting : [text](https://bbssolutions.in/__REFFERAL_BONUS/angularPrifileProblem/media.mp4)

Tried : [text](https://bbssolutions.in/__REFFERAL_BONUS/angularPrifileProblem/whatididmedia.mp4)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an observable about document scroll using rxjs

But first define four constants

```
export const MINSCROLL=20
export const MAXSCROLL=100
export const MIN_SIZE=50
export const MAX_SIZE=120
```

Then define an observable

```
height$=fromEvent(document,'scroll').pipe(
    startWith(null),
    map(()=>{
      const x=window.scrollY;
      if (x>MAXSCROLL)
        return MIN_SIZE;
      if (x<MINSCROLL)
        return MAX_SIZE

      return MAX_SIZE-(MAX_SIZE-MIN_SIZE)*(x-MINSCROLL)/(MAXSCROLL-MINSCROLL)
  }),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  )
```

See that you use map to transform the response. if window.scrollY is less than MIN_SCROLL return MAX_SIZE, if is greater than MAX_SCROLL return MIN-SIZE, otherwise return a "rule of three"

Then just use this observable in a div

```
<div class="top" [style.height.px]="obs$ |async" >
```

Where

```
.top
{
  position:fixed;
  background-color:white;
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  text-align:center;
}
```

See a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eih7c4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: let me implement this... and update you about this...thnx